# Why are they grammatical, "those things a thought," those a thought"?

Tags: grammaticality

It's a script from the book Metaphysics by Aristotle.
[image]

I wonder about grammaticality. In what way are "those things a thought" and "those a thought" grammatically correct? I thought at first they were appositions, but I think now there is omission of commas between these and those and "a thought"s are related with clauses themselves; I don't know why commas are omitted, though.
(They are located in line 4 and 5 repectively.)

Comment: Have you tried looking at other translations?

Comment: I would have included a comma. It's not "those things a thought", but "those things, _a thought about which_ is a single thought". The phrase I have italicised describes the 'things'.

Comment: @KateBunting Why do you think the writer didn't use the comma? Isn't it ungrammatical without a comma?

Comment: The use of commas is more a matter of personal style than grammar. I have no idea why the translator didn't use one here; it would have made the meaning clearer.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you.

Comment: (I wonder if the translator thought this is a defining relative clause and therefore shouldn't have a comma.)

Comment: @KateBunting Please write an answer, not comments.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - It was meant as a comment, not an authoritative answer.

Comment: There should not be a comma; insert the relative pronoun *that* to see that you have a restrictive relative clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is like asking what "man who" means in the sentence "I saw a man who worked at the shop." :)

Your sentence:

> This group comprises those things a thought about which is a single
> thought.

can be rephrased as:

> This group comprises those things **that you can think about in a
> single thought.**

So the second part of the sentence (in bold) describes the "things" in the first part.

I'll try to explain the grammar used in your original sentence with a fictional dialog of two philosophers:

```
Aristotle: You know what's interesting about these things?
Confusius: No, what?
Aristotle: A thought about these things is a single thought.
Confusius: Wow! You should totally put them in a group!
Aristotle: What group?
Confusius: A group of these things.
Aristotle: What things?
Confusius: The things that you think about in a single thought.
Aristotle: You mean, a group of things that when you think about them, the thought about them is a single thought?
Confusius: Totally!
Aristotle: Okay, look at the group I made!
Confusius: Wow! This group comprises those things a thought about which is a single thought!
```